# The word الله is not showing in a PDF file that was uploaded from html file

Tags: html, laravel, pdf, arabic

I wrote code that downloads PDF file to computer when the route is clicked, using Laravel. The PDF file is in Arabic and the word الله is not showing.

I tried adding laravel-arabic-html library but that did not work
and tried HTML tags (pre, blockquote).

The library I downloaded did not work because it kept showing an error:

> Call to a member function toArabicHTML() on string

When I tried to make text in html go from left to right, the word الله showed but not connected and of course from left to right, so i knew that the problem has to be with that exact word.

Can I use code to write it or what should I do?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You probably need to show us your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.